# springboot: implement mysql cdc

Tags: java, spring-boot, debezium

i'm trying to catch any changes on my MySQL local database with spring-boot
but when i run my project i get `Unable to instantiate connector class io.debezium.connector.mysql.mysqlconnector`

Does anyone have any tip to help me?

this my configuration code:

```
 @Bean
public io.debezium.config.Configuration studentConnector() {
    return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
            .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.mysql.mysqlconnector")
            .with("offset.storage",  "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
            .with("offset.storage.file.filename", "/cdc/offset.dat")
            .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", 60000)
            .with("name", "student-postgres-connector")
            .with("database.server.name", studentDBHost+"-"+studentDBName)
            .with("database.hostname", studentDBHost)
            .with("database.port", studentDBPort)
            .with("database.user", studentDBUserName)
            .with("database.password", studentDBPassword)
            .with("database.dbname", studentDBName)
            .with("table.whitelist", STUDENT_TABLE_NAME)
            .build();
}
```

this is my application log error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.connector.mysql.mysqlconnector
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:666) ~[debezium-embedded-1.3.1.Final.jar:1.3.1.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: `io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector`?

Comment: @sp00m i follow this tutorial https://github.com/sohangp/embedded-debezium

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use `MySqlConnector`, you need to change docker image from [`debezium/postgres`](https://github.com/sohangp/embedded-debezium/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L7) (that doesn't contain debezium mysql connector) to [`debezium/connect`](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect).

Comment: i change docker image and get some error. should I run the spring project in a container? @IskuskovAlexander

Comment: It's up to you. You can do this and your spring app will be automatically build and run by docker compose.